# Having volume issues when recording a podcast

Tags: audio, volume

When I'm recording a podcast with my two other co-hosts, lately the output sound has been fluctuating to loud and then very quiet levels seeminly randomly.  We've replaced the mics and cords with no change.  We have an USB mixer that the mics plug into and we record in Audacity.

When we tested the mics on their own (recording just two of us in the same room), the levels don't change.  However, our third host connects through Skype and that's when the issue happens.  We've updated Skype and that seems to have lessen the issue but not solved it completely.  The mics are how he hears us in the Skype settings.  When we started doing it this way, it wasn't a problem at all and everything was great but lately it's been happening leading to a longer editing process.

Can anyone offer an explanation or a solution?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could be either Skype or Windows automatically adjusting volume. See this: http://community.skype.com/t5/Windows-desktop-client/When-in-a-call-skype-lowers-the-volume-of-other-applications/m-p/112526/message-uid/112526/highlight/true#U112526?

Comment: Thanks, Todd.  Would this be the cause of the sound going up and down randomly throughout the recording process?

*EDIT* I checked this window and "Do nothing" is already selected.

Comment: Could it be window's audio enhancements? You switch them of in Playback Devices > Your speaker's properties.

Comment: Do your co-host uses heaphones while on skype? This could avoid the auto-volume of Skype